# Cannot Upload Image (HttpPostedFileBase is Null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image, file-upload

I tried to have an images uploader but when I click the browse and select image then submit my form the HttpPostedFileBase is null. Is there missing with my implementation? Please help.

**View**

```
<form action="Home/UploadImage" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" name="projectBgImage" id="projectBgImage"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Home Controller**

```
 public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase projectBgImage)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Debug Image**

[image]

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: @Ravi, +1. If you want, you add this link my question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `enctype attribute` your `form` element

```
<form action="Home/UploadImage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I suggest you to use `BeginForm` html-helper like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <p>
        <input type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" name="projectBgImage" id="projectBgImage"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

and Action Method with `[HttpPost]` annotation

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase projectBgImage)
{
    return View();
}
```

Extra Information : A nice blog post by Phil Haack  [Asp.net MVC Upload](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much it's now working! Thanks for suggesting what is better implementation this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In the View an `enctype` attribute is required to be set to `multipart/form-data`

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ImageUp", "YourUpController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Second,
On top of your action method make sure you have the `HTTPPOST` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase projectBgImage)
```