# Dont get an attachment with email asp.net mvc 4 Model.ProjectInformation = null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have feedback form on my site and I need to add attachment to email
I have

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProjectInformation, null, new { type = "file", @class = "input-file" })
```

=

```
<input type="file" id="ProjectInformation">
```

and I write that code in my controller

```
        //Attachment
        if (Model.ProjectInformation != null && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProjectInformation.FileName)))
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase hpf = this.Request.Files[Model.ProjectInformation.FileName];
            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var attach = new Attachment(hpf.InputStream, Model.ProjectInformation.FileName);
                msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
            }
        }
```

but I get email without attachment  and when I check in debugger I see
  `Model.ProjectInformation = null`

but I dont understand why?

Comment: Check [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404398/cannot-upload-image-httppostedfilebase-is-null/15404436#15404436)

Comment: but I have in my controller `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model)` How can I add the HTTPPOST attribute in my action method?

Comment: I added `@using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "feedback-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` and `public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model, HttpPostedFileBase ProjectInformation)` but I get error http://i.imgur.com/uQhMvtA.png what's wrong?

Comment: `ProjectInformation` is a property of `FeedbackForm` class ? If yes, then you dont need second parameter (`HttpPostedFileBase ProjectInformation`) of action-method. File is already binded to your `model.ProjectInformation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.ProjectInformation` is already a `HttpPostedFileBase` that is come from your view, you dont need to try to get file from request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model)
{
    //Attachment
    if (Model.ProjectInformation != null && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProjectInformation.FileName)))
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Model.ProjectInformation;
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var attach = new Attachment(hpf.InputStream, Model.ProjectInformation.FileName);
            msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i again get in `HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Model.ProjectInformation;` hpf = null, I cant understand why!

Comment: And when I try to add an attachment I dont get email at all.

Comment: try to use Model.ProjectInformation directly in if block. I mean `if(Model.ProjectInformation.ContentLength > 0)`

Comment: It seems I need to add the second parameter here `public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model, HttpPostedFileBase ProjectInformation)` if I dont add it I dont get email, but with this parameter it works.