# upload image using MVC 4 causes to save an invalid image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to upload an image using **MVC4** so i create a view that holds an input file to select file by user :

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
    </div>
    <input id="ImageUrl" title="Upload a student image" type="file" name="ImageUrl" />
```

The **ImageUrl** holds the name of file ,after submit i send this form to my action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 public ActionResult Create(Student student)

        {
            student.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            if (objcheck.CheckUserExistAlready(student.Email))
            {                   

                        string strLocation = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
                        Request.SaveAs(strLocation + @"\" + student.ImageUrl,true);
                        obj.AddNewStudent(student);
                        obj.Save();                      

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
        }
```

This action works without any errors ,but it save an invalid image in **App_Data**!!!why ?

My Model:

```
public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            this.Scores = new HashSet<Score>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("نام")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام خانوادگی را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("نام خانوادگی")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "کد ملی را وارد کنید")]
        [StringLength(10,ErrorMessage = "کد ملی باید ده رقمی باشد",MinimumLength = 10)]
        [DisplayName("کد ملی")]
        public string IntNo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "نام پدر را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("نام پدر")]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "محل تولد را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("محل تولد ")]
        public string BirthLocation { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "تاریخ تولد را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("تاریخ تولد")]
        public string Birthday { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "آدرس عکس را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("تصویر")]

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "رشته را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("رشته")]
        public string Major { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "مقطع را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("مقطع")]
        public string Degree { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "شماره شناسنامه را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("شماره شناسنامه")]
        public string IdentNo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "آدرس را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("آدرس")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "شماره همراه را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("شماره همراه")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ایمیل را وارد کنید")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage = "ایمیل نامعتبر است")]
        [DisplayName("ایمیل")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "کلمه عبور را وارد کنید")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("کلمه عبور")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("تاریخ ثبت نام ")]
        public System.DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "شماره دانشجویی را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("شماره دانشجویی/دانشجویی")]
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "وضعیت را وارد کنید")]
        [DisplayName("وضعیت")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Score> Scores { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

My image that saved by my code:

[image]

Best regards.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `student.ImageUrl` should be `HttpPostedFileBase` type, and you cant get this type as string. So, you are wrong to do wrong :)

Comment: Share your model and `student.ImageUrl` output

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi i shared it

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi can i should change my action to this : HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[0];
                        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);
                        string strLocation = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
                        Request.Files[0].SaveAs(strLocation + @"\" + filename);
                        obj.AddNewStudent(student);
                        obj.Save();

Comment: @EA get your file using HttpPostedFileBase save it in the folder then in your imageurl property save the path to your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model:**

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Scores = new HashSet<Score>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl { get; set; }
    ...
```

**View:** (dont forget `enctype="multipart/form-data"`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { id = "form", enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
    </div>
    <input id="ImageUrl" title="Upload a student image" type="file" name="ImageUrl" />
    ...
```

**Controller:**

```
...
student.ImageUrl.SaveAs("your path here");
...
```

**Refrences:**

[file upload mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404398/cannot-upload-image-httppostedfilebase-is-null/15404436#15404436)

[files upload](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

Comment: public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl { get; set; } ,the c# can resolve the HttpPostedFileBase ,which references should i add ?

Comment: And the winner is ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx - System.Web